# How to rename files in batch, remove all characters after ".mp3" in file name?

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I think that windows powershell can be used to do this. I have a stack of mp3 files which have problem with their file name. There is a stream of characters in file name of each file after the terms ".mp3" which prevents them from being identified as mp3 files. I have tried renaming each file manually but am fed up now. I want to automate the process.

It should be possible to use powershell for this and perhaps there are other options which I am not aware of. The script needs to read each file name in the folder and if the name has any more characters after ".mp3" in the filename, all the subsequent characters shall be deleted. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$files=ls -Name *.mp3*

foreach ($file in $files) {
Rename-Item $file $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf(".mp3")+4)
}
```

However, it's too long solution.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

ok. so the wildcards are weird with the rename command.

this *DOES* work

```
ren "*.mp3*" "??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????.mp3"
```

as long as there are as many ? as the longest filename

refer to this if you want details

https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards

Comment: I tried it.. it works. are you sure you did it exactly?

Comment: That's odd. I just did this: `ren *.mp3* *.mp3` and my test file was "1.mp3.asdf233gg" and it became "1.mp3.mp3"

Comment: do you care about keeping their original names?

Comment: and are all the files there, mp3 files? or supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

First I'm sure the Community would have liked to have seen you try *something* so that we could have helped you fix it. However other users have provided solutions so I would like to chime in from a PowerShell perspective

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter "*.mp3*" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "\.mp3.*",".mp3"}
```

This will take all files with ".mp3" somewhere in the file name. Then it will rename them by taking everything after and including ".mp3" with just that. If you have a file with ".mp3" more than once this would be an issue. Easily fixed but I will keep it terse by accepting that potential.

Comment: I did not know where to start from, I am not an expert in this field. I could have written a C program perhaps, but I know that a solution exists as a 1 line powershell command so I posted the question